# Geometrical progression with any number row

Tags: math, numbers, series

I can have any number row which consists from 2 to 10 numbers. And from this row, I have to get geometrical progression.

For example:
Given number row: `125 5 625` I have to get answer `5`. Row: `128 8 512` I have to get answer `4`.

Can you give me a hand? I don't ask for a program, just a hint, I want to understand it by myself and write a code by myself, but damn, I have been thinking the whole day and couldn't figure this out.

Thank you.

**DON'T WRITE THE WHOLE PROGRAM!**

Guys, you don't get it, I can't just simple make a division. I actually have to get geometrical progression + show all numbers. In `128 8 512` row all numbers would be: `8 32 128 512`

Comment: your second row doesn't make sense, are you sure you said it correctly?

Comment: Your explanation is a complete mess. So each of your rows is a list of numbers from a geometric sequence, but out of order and missing entries. Welbog seems to have the correct solution

Comment: His explanation makes sense if you take the time to read the question and understand what "geometric sequence" means.

Comment: @Amoss: Yes, I am sorry, my English is a little bit broken :)

Comment: @Welbog: Yes, I read it, several times and I know what a geometric sequence is. Perhaps you should consider what a "sequence" is, and what an unordered list of elements from a sequence is, the difference between the two and why it would be an important detail to mention.

Comment: @hey: no worries, calling it a complete mess may have been a bit harsh :) but I was trying to point out what extra details to add next time.

Comment: For clarification: I'm assuming you want answers of the form (a, b), where the input numbers of the form ab^n. Do you need _a_ to be an integer when possible? (See my response to Frisco's answer below for an example of when this can be an issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Seth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824530/geometrical-progression-with-any-number-row/3824811#3824811) is the right one. I'm leaving this answer here to help elaborate on why the answer to `128 8 512` is `4` because people seem to be having trouble with that.

---

A geometric progression's elements can be written in the form `c*b^n` where `b` is the number you're looking for (`b` is also necessarily greater than 1), `c` is a constant and `n` is some arbritrary number.

So the best bet is to start with the smallest number, factorize it and look at all possible solutions to writing it in the `c*b^n` form, then using that `b` on the remaining numbers. Return the largest result that works.

So for your examples:

```
125 5 625
```

Start with 5. 5 is prime, so it can be written in only one way: `5 = 1*5^1`. So your `b` is 5. You can stop now, assuming you know the row is in fact geometric. If you need to determine whether it's geometric then test that `b` on the remaining numbers.

```
128 8 512
```

`8` can be written in more than one way: `8 = 1*8^1`, `8 = 2*2^2`, `8 = 2*4^1`, `8 = 4*2^1`. So you have three possible values for `b`, with a few different options for `c`. Try the biggest first. `8` doesn't work. Try `4`. It works! `128 = 2*4^3` and `512 = 2*4^4`. So `b` is `4` and `c` is `2`.

```
3 15 375
```

This one is a bit mean because the first number is prime but isn't `b`, it's `c`. So you'll need to make sure that if your first `b`-candidate doesn't work on the remaining numbers you have to look at the next smallest number and decompose it. So here you'd decompose 15: `15 = 15*?^0` (degenerate case), `15 = 3*5^1`, `15 = 5*3^1`, `15 = 1*15^1`. The answer is 5, and `3 = 3*5^0`, so it works out.

Comment: @hey: That makes it easy when you happen to find a prime in your sequence.

Comment: There was no requirement that c and b be integers. If you add that then the problem becomes fairly trivial.

Comment: @c-urchin: You're right. I just assumed that from the example rows. Please consider this answer invalid unless `b` and `c` are integers.

Comment: @Welbog: I don't get the solution. If the row is `3, 15, 125` I get `b` 3, but it is not the answer.

Comment: @hey: You said they're guaranteed to be geometric, but `3, 15, 125` is not geometric. If they're not guaranteed to be geometric then you need to test your hypothetical `b` against the other members even when the smallest is prime.

Comment: @Welbog : Oh, I am sorry. I meant row like this 3, 15, 375, then g. progression is 5

Comment: @hey: Understood. You'll need to be able to have `n=0`. Let me update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Welbog: Can you, please, inspect the last row `1500 300 37500 12`, the g.prog is 5 here? Thank you. I don't exactly understand that `c*b^n`

Answer (score 2):

***Edit: I think this should be correct now.***

*This algorithm does not rely on factoring, only on the Euclidean Algorithm, and a close variant thereof. This makes it slightly more mathematically sophisticated then a solution that uses factoring, but it will be MUCH faster. If you understand the Euclidean Algorithm and logarithms, the math should not be a problem.*

(1) Sort the set of numbers. You have numbers of the form `ab^{n1} < .. < ab^{nk}`.

Example: `(3 * 2, 3*2^5, 3*2^7, 3*2^13)`

(2) Form a new list whose nth element of the (n+1)st element of the sorted list divided by the (n)th. You now have `b^{n2 - n1}, b^{n3 - n2}, ..., b^{nk - n(k-1)}`.

(Continued) Example: `(2^4, 2^2, 2^6)`

Define `d_i = n_(i+1) - n_i` (do not program this -- you couldn't even if you wanted to, since the `n_i` are unknown -- this is just to explain how the program works).

(Continued) Example: `d_1 = 4, d_2 = 2, d_3 = 6`

Note that in our example problem, we're free to take either `(a = 3, b = 2)` or `(a = 3/2, b = 4)`. The bottom line is any power of the "real" `b` that divides all entries in the list from step (2) is a correct answer. It follows that we can raise `b` to any power that divides all the `d_i` (in this case any power that divides 4, 2, and 6). The problem is we know neither `b` nor the `d_i`. But if we let `m = gcd(d_1, ... d_(k-1))`, then we CAN find `b^m`, which is sufficient.

NOTE: Given `b^i` and `b^j`, we can find `b^gcd(i, j)` using:

`log(b^i) / log(b^j) = (i log b) / (j log b) = i/j`

This permits us to use a modified version of the Euclidean Algorithm to find `b^gcd(i, j)`. The "action" is all in the exponents: addition has been replaced by multiplication, multiplication with exponentiation, and (consequently) quotients with logarithms:

```
import math
def power_remainder(a, b):
    q = int(math.log(a) / math.log(b))
    return a / (b ** q)        

def power_gcd(a, b):
    while b != 1:
    a, b = b, power_remainder(a, b)
    return a
```

(3) Since all the elements of the original set differ by powers of `r = b^gcd(d_1, ..., d_(k-1))`, they are all of the form `cr^n`, as desired. However, `c` may not be an integer. Let me know if this is a problem.

Comment: I wish I had thought of this one. +1 for being right and a lot better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to factorize the numbers and find the greatest number they have in common. But be careful, factorization has an exponential complexity so it might stop working if you get big numbers in the row.

Comment: there is nothing 'exponential` about finding the gcd. Loopup the euclidean algorithm. This is not exactly cutting edge technology.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth You are right, originally I thought he wanted the smallest number but after reading the comments I just changed the word "smallest" to "greatest" without thinking about the implications.

Comment: if it's the smallest number, then that can be gotten as smallest divisor of the gcd which is, again, not exponential.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to know the Greatest Common Divisor of all numbers in a row.

One method is to check if they all can be divided by the smaller number in the row.

If not, try half the smaller number in the row.

Then keep going down until you find a number that divides them all or your divisor equals 1.

Comment: This method won't work, since (among several other reasons) the smallest number need not be divisible by two. If you're trying to find GCDs, use the Euclidean Algorithm.

Comment: The smallest number does not need to be divided by two. But no number is divisible by any number greater than its half. Thats why there is no need to try them.

Answer (score 0):

[Seth Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824530/geometrical-progression-with-any-number-row/3824811#3824811) is not correct, applyin that solution does not solves `128 8 2048` row for example (2*4^x), you get:
`8 128 2048` =>
`16 16` =>
`GCD = 16`

It is true that the solution is a factor of this result but you will need to factor it and check one by one what is the correct answer, in this case you will need to check the solutions factors in reverse order `16, 8, 4, 2` until you see 4 matches all the conditions.

Comment: Actually, {8, 128, 2048} is ALSO from the sequence (1/2)16^n. 16 is a valid answer (unless we insist the the constant be an integer, which is reasonable). There WAS a related problem, which I think I've now fixed without requiring the use of factorization.